# Count the frequency of each element categorical values in python

Tags: python, numpy, frequency

Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

For example I have:

```
x = np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'u'])
```

Desired outcome:

```
[2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1]
```

Comment: You can select an answer even after your question is closed. I'd recommend doing so, since the relatively new arguments to np.unique make the answer more efficient than the accepted one of the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts` and `return_inverse` enabled:

```
_, inverse, count = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True, return_count=True)
result = count[inverse]
```

Comment: You missed return_count argument

Comment: @tstanisl. Wow. Much appreciated :)